# How do i fix this? (Simple "Rotation" Script)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

So i have this script that rotates a point around my "character", it worked until i added a minimap using the canvas ui element, now only works on the bottom left side of the screen.
[Here you can see more clearly what im talking about.](https://youtu.be/fIMFdzvQCPY)

this is my script:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerAim : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        AimMouse();
    }
    void AimMouse()
    {
        Vector3 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
        mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos);
        Vector2 direction = new Vector2(
            mousePos.x - transform.position.x,
            mousePos.y - transform.position.y
            );
        transform.up = direction;
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like maybe the Aim or AimAxis got moved to [0,0] in world coordinates.

Comment: "How do I fix this?" *could* be the title applied to well over half of all of the questions asked here on SO. Your title is your chance to "sell" your question to would-be answerers. Make it *relevant* to your question please.

Comment: Instead of assigning to transform.up you could use transform.LookAt, or get lookatDirection from a Quaternion, and take rotation from there.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be willing to bet your minimap uses a second camera, correct?  Do both cameras have the MainCamera tag?  If so, then your code that calls Camera.main would have undefined behaviour as to which camera it actually uses.  Most likely, it's using the minimap camera for the ScreenToWorldPoint call, which is giving you the unexpected behaviour.

What you need to do is either (a) remove the MainCamera tag from the minimap camera object, or (b) add a Camera reference to your script, and reference it directly in the code.